# Read .php files with JWPlayer 7

Tags: php, jwplayer

I try to secure my videos with a token system, but my player can't read the .php files, do you know what's wrong ?

My jwplayer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jwplayer.key="mykey";</script>
    <div id="player_div" style="outline:0px;">Loading...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("player_div");
            playerInstance.setup({
            abouttext: "Player",
            aboutlink: "http://mywebsite.com",
            autostart: "0",
            startparam: "start",
            aspectratio: "12:7",
            width: "100%",
            'type': 'mp4',
            image: "/content/img/mp4-poster.jpg",
            sources: [{
                file: "test.php"
                },{
                file: "test.php",
                "default": true,
            }]
        });
    </script>
```

And my test.php:

```
clearstatcache();

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("video.mp4"));
readfile("video.mp4");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code instead for the sources block:

```
sources: [{
    file: "test.php",
    type: "mp4"
}, {
    file: "test.php",
    "default": true,
    type: "mp4"
}]
```

Comment: Even though this works...when streaming audio ...I am unable to seek...the file always just restarts.

Comment: You might want to try to set a different type then, like mp3 or aac.